# Adding Temporary Dyno for Spike in Traffic to my site (Heroku Rails App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, request, dyno

I am expecting a large increase in traffic tomorrow(press, etc) to my website. I want to be able to manage the traffic without it going down. I know that I have to add dyno's and the cost is not too prohibitive because it is only temporary to keep the queue down.

I am using New Relic Add-On to Monitor

This post is really helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/394602/how-to-prepare-for-a-huge-spike-in-traffic-for-launching-a-website-hosted-on-her

However after reading that post and pouring over heroku docs I have not been able to figure out how I actually do this...

What command can I run or from what interface can I spin up a new dyno to handle the added web traffic? Then, with what command do I run or from what interface do I eliminate that extra dyno when the traffic has return to normal levels?

Heroku talk about a bunch of different types of dyno's etc but I have no idea which one I am supposed to use and then how to actually spin up a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has an [platform-api gem](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api) that will be useful for you in this case. First add the gem to your `Gemfile` and install it.

```
gem platform-api
```

Once installed, setup the heroku client, preferably in an initializer

```
$heroku = PlatformAPI.connect(ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY', default_headers: {'Accept' => 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3'})
```

You can find how to get an Heroku API KEY [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart)

Now, to the scaling part. I'm guessing you have some internal metrics to decide when to scale (by process count, request count, etc). The below command will scale up the number of dynos you require,

```
$heroku.formation.update(APP_NAME, PROCESS_NAME, {quantity: DYNO_COUNT})
```

This will scale the app's specified process to X number of dynos whenever required.

You can use the same command to scale down your number of dynos. Also, below command will help you get the number of dynos currently provisioned for a particular process

```
info = $heroku.formation.info(APP_NAME, PROCESS_NAME)
info['quantity']
```

To get the number of ALL dynos provisioned to your app, use

```
$heroku.app.info(APP_NAME)
```

**EDIT**:

In case you prefer it to do manually, then you can do this in the heroku's dashboard itself. Or if you prefer command line, install heroku [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and below is the command for scaling the app.

```
heroku ps:scale process_name=dyno_count -a app_name
```

To get the list of dynos provisioned

```
heroku ps -a app_name
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it manually as I monitor new relic numbers?

Comment: I would rather not automate it for this right now. Maybe down the line but at this point I just want manual control.

Comment: where on the heroku dashboard page? I don't see where.

Comment: In the app specific page in heroku, you can see sliders for each process you have provisioned with edit option on the right. You can slide the number of dynos using that.

Comment: On heroku dashboard I only see what I assume a web dyno(turned on) and a worker dyno(turned off). I am able to turn the worker dyno on but I am not able to add more than 1 web or worker dyno... Maybe this is part of my heroku dev hobby plan or something.

Comment: @Javier Both the names Web and Worker are specified by you in the procfile. Scale the one you marked for web process.

Comment: @Javier I think you're on an Free / Hobby plan and that's why you have only turn on and off option. Above the list of dynos, you can see the option to change your dyno type to professional. Then you will have that option.

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Comment: Thank you, yes this was it!